# sas -calculate new varibale for a combination of varibales from a data set

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm working through a complex problem, where in I have a dataset with 900 observations and 12 variables and here is the sample for reference

```
S1  I1      s2     xoq  sxoq    running_sxoq
96  2913    501     50  1      1
96  2913    1315    50  10  11
96  2913    1322    50  9   20
96  2913    1345    50  15  35
96  2913    1366    50  1   36
96  2913    1426    50  26  62
96  2913    1522    50  18  80
96  2913    1582    50  42  122
96  2913    5789    50  40  162
96  21051   501      1  35  35
96  21051   1315    1   58  93
96  21051   1322    1   144 237
96  21051   1340    1   48  285
96  21051   1345    1   32  317
96  21051   1366    1   41  358
96  21051   1426    1   25  383
96  21051   1522    1   36  419
96  21051   1582    1   39  458
96  21051   5789    1   67  525
```

for each combination of s1 and I1 columns I need to calculate a new column such that its value is equal to xoq from the sum of first avilable sxoq columns.
for example for the first s1 and i1 pair (96,2913) , xoq is 50, the desired calculated column will have values=sxoq until the sum is 50, the rest of the values will be 0.

```
desired output
    S1  I1       s2    xoq  sxoq  running_sxoq  calculated
    96  2913    501     50  1   1   1
    96  2913    1315    50  10  11  10
    96  2913    1322    50  9   20  9
    96  2913    1345    50  15  35  15
    96  2913    1366    50  1   36  1
    96  2913    1426    50  26  62  14
    96  2913    1522    50  18  80  0
    96  2913    1582    50  42  122 0
    96  2913    5789    50  40  162 0
    96  21051   501      1  35  35  1
    96  21051   1315    1   58  93  0
    96  21051   1322    1   144 237 0
    96  21051   1340    1   48  285 0
    96  21051   1345    1   32  317 0
    96  21051   1366    1   41  358 0
    96  21051   1426    1   25  383 0
    96  21051   1522    1   36  419 0
    96  21051   1582    1   39  458 0
    96  21051   5789    1   67  525 0
```

I have tried so many different options, but each one seems to go in a never ending path.

firstly, I concatenated s1 and I1 columns and used last. to identify each unique combination of S1andI1 columns

I also tried reading the values into multidimensional array, but it does not seem to work.

How can I get to the desired output?

Comment: Post the code you've tried please. I don't think you need an array, a basic data step should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to use BY group processing.  You will probably want to make a new running total that resets to zero when you start a new group.

So basically to get the truncated amount that you need to increase the running sum so that caps out at the value of `XOQ` you can just use a `MIN(,)` function. Then to get the zeros for when the running sum is past the value of `XOQ` you can just use a `MAX(,)` function.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by s1 i1 ;
  if first.i1 then new_running=0;
  want = max(0,min(sxoq,xoq-new_running));
  new_running + sxoq ;
run;
```